# How to pass authorization token from webapp to rest service

Tags: java, ajax, rest, jetty, keycloak

I have a JS app deployed in Jetty. I have enabled keycloak security by setting security handler on jetty `WebAppContext`

```
WebAppContext wac = null;

String webAppPath = "/../../server/webapp/mywebapp";            
wac = new WebAppContext(webAppPath, "/mywebapp");
wac.addFilter(GzipFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
wac.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
context.setSecurityHandler(keycloakSecurity);
```

When I access the above webapp url, flow works fine, I am prompted for authentication and on successful authentication, I am redirected to webapp. 
However, any rest calls that this webapp(ajax calls) makes to the server (which are also protected via keycloak ) are unauthorized (401).

**Do I need to explicitly set authorization headers in ajax calls or enabling security handler in `WebAppContext` should be enough and am missing some config?**

(The rest calls are accessible if I send the token directly to them, but not through above webapp automatically)

In angular JS , I am usinng `RestAngular` like this:

```
app.factory('DesignVaultRestangular', ['Restangular', '$location', function(Restangular, $location) {
  var url = baseURL;
  var location = $location.search();
  if (location && location.url)
    url = location.url;
  url = url + '/api/secured/';
  return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
    RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl(url);
    RestangularConfigurer.setDefaultHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'withCredentials': true
    });
  });
}]);
```

**EDIT:** Request headers

[image]

Comment: can you try removing the default headers configuration part ?

Comment: @CamilleVienot After your answer, i am only setting content type header in default header. Have already removed withCredentials from headers.

Comment: If you're using Spring Security Adapter for keycloack, the session tracked by the jsessionid should hold the security context, so you don't need to pass the authorization header.

Comment: @CamilleVienot no i am not using spring security

Comment: The jetty adapter also relies on the jsessionID, if bearer-only is set to false in keycloak conf

Comment: @CamilleVienot the issue is not on the jetty side. I am able to access api through postman. The issue comes when webapp comes in picture.

Answer (score 1):

Authorization headers are required whether you access via the URL or via ajax call.

You can pass the HTTP authorization headers in the format mentioned below along with your request. Different APIs and tools have different ways to set the HTTP headers.

```
     Authorization: <authorization scheme>  < authorization parameters >
```

Please note that the credentials are set as required in the belowline. You need to change it if it is not required
     'withCredentials': true

Comment: Can you explain the line "You need to change if it is not required".

Comment: Also , how do I explicitly set the token. I know it can be done like this : `Authorization : Bearer <token_value>`, but keycloak is just setting a jSessionId in the browser cache, it's not setting a access token in the cache